# How to produce antiquarks?

Tags: particle-physics, collision, antimatter, quarks, accelerator-physics

I've read a few books and articles about particle physics, accelerators and colliders, but I still don't understand how the quarks in the protons 'turn' into antiquarks. 
I know the protons are sent at very high energy on a target, but how is this target special?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Hugo.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quarks in a proton do not turn into anti-quarks. With a high energy interaction between a quark in the proton and some other particle, be that a lepton or another quark, a quark-antiquark pair $q,~\bar q$ is produced. The color charge of quarks is a conserved quantity, so it does not flip to its opposite charge, just as a positive electric charged particle can't flip to a negative charge.